# Redirect destination nextjs and react native expo web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, expo, react-native-web

I am trying to redirect a url to another url in my website as seen below, in nextjs and expo react native web.

I do not have an about page, but I have other pages under the about folder and would like to redirect any  incoming request to /about path to the /about/company.

Below is my last implementation as seen in [Nextjs next.config.js Redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects), and still I have not been able to get it to work.

```
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports = withExpo(
  withImages(
    withFonts({
      projectRoot: __dirname,
    })
  ), {
    async redirects() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/about',
          destination: '/about/company',
          permanent: true,
        },
      ];
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried a barebones `next.config.js` with just redirects to see if it works? I would try a configuration without the wrappers i.e. withExpo, withImage and withFonts. Once able to get the simple config working, maybe add other options one by one. I am worried there is an issue with the way the options have been combined here.

Comment: Try moving the `async redirects()` to the innermost object in `withFonts` (right after the `projectRoot` entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving the `async redirects()` into the innermost object `withFonts` worked, i.e.

```
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports = withExpo(
  withImages(
    withFonts({
      projectRoot: __dirname,
      async redirects() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/about',
            destination: '/about/company',
            permanent: true,
          },
        ];
      },
    })
  )
);
```